# Nginx - Redirect cookie logic causes 404 errors

Tags: nginx

I have the following config:

```
upstream ring {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    root /home/app/public;

    index index.dev.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @ring;
    }

    location @ring {
        proxy_pass http://ring;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

It serves as a file, then directory, then proxies through to the app server.  This works as expected.  However, now, I wish to redirect the user to an about.html page the FIRST time they visit the site.  So I changed the config to the following:

```
upstream ring {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    root /home/app/public;

    index index.dev.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {

        set $seen false;

        if ($http_cookie ~* "seen") {
           set $seen true;
        }

        if ($seen = false) {
           add_header Set-Cookie seen=1;
           return 302 $scheme://$host/about.html;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ @ring;
    }

    location @ring {
        proxy_pass http://ring;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

The redirect logic now works (no cookie redirects to about.html with a new cookie set, subsequent requests fall through to the main index.html page).  BUT, now any url to the app server result in 404 errors.  The @ring location is no longer being served at all.

I'm probably making a silly mistake but don't understand nginx well enough to debug this.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out "if is evil" in nginx (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), and that this is a bug due to "if" being imperative and the rest of the config being declarative.

The following change works and does everything I wanted.  The trick is not do anything inside of an if besides return or rewrite.  And then also to use nginx internal redirect code of 418.

```
upstream ring {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    root /home/app/public;

    index index.dev.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {

        error_page 418 = @about;

        if ($cookie_seen != 1) {
          return 418;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ @ring;
    }

    location @about {
        add_header Set-Cookie seen=1;
        return 302 $scheme://$host/about.html;
    }

    location @ring {
        proxy_pass http://ring;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```